# How to grant access to Intranet site to External Users?

Tags: alternate-access-mapping, user, access

Our company recently acquired few small companies. We are in the transition for getting all the files and documentation. I created a "Document Center" site for this project.

What is the best way give access to external users for our intranet site?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have them VPN in and then access it the same way everyone else does.  Seriously.  Opening up your Intranet site to the Internet is inviting no end of trouble and security risks.

For example, is your intranet farm completely up to date on its patches?  How about the underlying OS?  Does the service account that is used for the exposed application pool have any additional permissions?  Has it been white-hat tested in any way?

How bad would it be if a hacker were to gain access to your Intranet site?  Is there compromising data on there?  Passwords?  Server listings?  Financial data?  HR Data?

If this *really* has to happen and you don't have the option of standing up another farm in the DMZ, I'd recommend creating a completely new Web Application that uses a completely new Service account with the least privileges possible.  Then configuring your firewall to allow traffic to that web app and only that web app and only on the specific port (preferably SSL).  Bear in mind, this just reduces the risk but you are still in serious trouble if someone gets through.  This is also *NOT* recommended by Microsoft in any way nor would I advise having something like this up 5 seconds longer than you absolutely need to.  If you can disable it for non-working hours, so much the better.

Again, the VPN is really your best option for this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helps to understand under laying factors. So the best approach is to create a new sp servers and create web app and extend that web app to extranet. Then use tool like metalogix to migrate content from intranet site to extranet site.

Comment: You would need to stand up a new farm in the DMZ (the area between your internal firewall and you internet firewall).  Hopefully this area is on a separate domain as well but you would need to set up a one-way trust between your internal domain and the DMZ domain so that users could still access it using their internal accounts.  Done properly, this is quite safe as accounts in the DMZ Domain would have *zero* permissions on the internal domain.  In this situation, you would also not need to copy content unless there is specific content that needs a one-way push from the intranet.